# Is a linear functional that maps the first number of $v \in \ell^2$ bounded?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

Let $v \in \ell^2$ be a sequence of $\ell^2$ over the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$

Let $T:V \to \mathbb{C}$, $T(v)=v_1$ be the linear functional where $T(v)$ is the first number of the sequence $v$

My question is if $T$ is bounded.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: how does a component of a vector in a Hilbert space compare to the total length of the vector?

Comment: Are you hinting me that is bounded, $||T||<1$ ? @Malkoun

Comment: I am hinting that $||T|| \leq 1$ (unless I am making some stupid mistake somewhere).

Comment: ok @Malkoun thanks for you hint